# Operator norm and continuity

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

I've read in the solution of an exercise: "$T$ has a finite norm, thus $T$ is continuous".

We are in a normed vector space $(V,||.||)$ and $T$ is a linear selfmap over the vector space $V$. The purpose of the exercise is to show that the set $L_w=\{v\in V:T(v)=w\}$ is closed. The first statement in the solution is the one above, and once showed continuity of $T$, the exercise is pretty straightforward.

Since I am working with linear operators in normed vector spaces, my idea is that it is linked with the equivalence of boundedness and continuity of an operator, but I am not sure. Is my idea right? If not, why the statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of a linear operator $L:V\to V$ is the smallest $M$ such that:

$$
||Lv||\le M||v|| \quad \forall v \in V
$$

So, your idea is correct:  a linear operator $L$ in a  normed spaces $V$ is bounded if and only if it is a continuous linear operator ([here a simple proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity)).